# Mobile CSS height 100% + browser chrome?

Tags: css, mobile, fullscreen

Im want a div to take up 100% of the viewport for mobile devices. Initially I just set it’s height and width to 100%.

However now I’m hiding the browser chrome with the following JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
window.scrollTo(0, 1) }, 
100);
```

The result is that the height is 100% minus the browser chrome height. Also, the javascript works by scrolling down the page enough that the chrome is hidden, and this can only happen if the page is taller than the div im using.

How can I get around this? Is the only way to use device detection and add the browser chrome height value in pixels on a per device basis? Id like to avoid this if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm not wrong your problem is mostly related to Safari iPhone.

The easiest solution is probably to check for the a page height  change every set interval, and change your container's height accordingly. No CSS solution is working, in my experience

```
var prevPageHeight = 0;

function setHeight() {
    $('#container').height( window.innerHeight );
    prevPageHeight = window.innerHeight;
}

setInterval( function() {
  if ( window.innerHeight != prevPageHeight ) {
    setHeight();
  }
}, 500);

setHeight();
```

This solution also consider orientation change.
I'm pretty sure it could easily optimized binding the function to the orientationChange and scroll events.

Comment: Yes im focusing in iPhone at the moment as I dont yet have an Android to test on. Does your solution take into account that fact that only the top browser chrome can be hidden? The bottom chrome with the back and forward button etc cannot be hidden. Thanks

Comment: It takes in account the address bar and eventually the developer bar, yes. The bottom navigation bar can be hided if you save your site as a home screen app, and even in that case it would work.

Comment: Whats the developer bar? I know that its possible to hide all the browser chrome if users save the site to the home screen by using meta tags, but I dont think my users will do this.

Comment: The developer bar can be enabled under Settings - Safari - Advanced - Debug console (on iOS5, a bit different on iOS4). It appears just below the address bar and shows general errors and your console.log()s.